# Android API 22 and 23 change causes flattening OpenGL 3d objects

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I have written application which is using OpenGL ES. I was testing it on emulated and real Nexus 5, with Android 6 (API 23) on it.

During tests on older Android versions (API 22-) it came out, that my 3d object is missing one dimension.

After statring app, it looks like this in both cases (view is set to -z, and y axis is up here):

[image: view when it seems to be working]

but when rotating this, there is a difference in behavior in API 22 (or lower) and 23.

Case API 22 (or lower):

[image: API 22 case - z axis on model is missing]

Object is flat - Z axis on model seems to be missing, however light is calculated properly (with proper Z values).

Case API 23 (desired one):

[image: API 23 case - rotation works]

All screenshots are from emulator; I have tested it only on one real device, with API 23 (Nexus 5), and it works there.

Rotation is done by touch events, and handled by code like this:

```
Matrix.rotateM(mCurrentRotation, 0, mDeltaRotationY, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0, mCurrentRotation, 0);
```

OpenGL version is set in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

For me it seems that something has changed in behavior of model or view martix.

**EDIT**
As requested in comment:
Matrices are created in my rendered, which is extending GLSurfaceView.Renderer
I was following http://www.learnopengles.com/ tutorial to prepare this.

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 glUnused, EGLConfig config) {
    ...
    final float eyeX = 0.0f;
    final float eyeY = 0.0f;
    final float eyeZ = 7.0f;
    final float lookX = 0.0f;
    final float lookY = 0.0f;
    final float lookZ = 0.0f;
    final float upX = 0.0f;
    final float upY = 1.0f;
    final float upZ = 0.0f;

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, lookX, lookY, lookZ, upX, upY, upZ);
    ...
}


public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 glUnused, int width, int height) {
    ...
    final float ratio = width / height;
    final float left = -ratio;
    final float right = ratio;
    final float bottom = -1.0f;
    final float top = 1.0f;
    final float near = 1.0f;
    final float far = 20.0f;

    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
    ...
}


public void onDrawFrame(GL10 glUnused) {
    ...
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mMVPMatrix, 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: It seems like a problem in the view and project matrix that you sent to your shaders. Plz post how you are creating them.

Comment: @codetiger I've added snippets above

Comment: If you would rather see whole renderer code, it is here https://github.com/walkon23/foraminifera/blob/master/ForamMobile/src/main/java/OpenGL/MyGLRenderer.java

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue is old already, but I've faced the same issue today.
So just in case somebody else encounters this, I identified the problem.

Whenever you call `Matrix.multiplyMM(float[] result, ...)` the 'result' float array must be equal neither to the left-hand-side matrix nor to the right-hand-side one.

On Android Marshmallow (or above) this does not seem to be a problem though... but below it might be a good idea to call the `.clone()` on the resulting matrix first and passing this then as the left/right-hand-side matrix instead.

Long story short, for `Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0);` the second `mMVPMatrix` needs to be replaced by `mMVPMatrix.clone()` for this to work properly.